# How to output DOM Value?

Tags: php, dom

Hello my friends i got a problem :S
I am a really noob in php and i need help.

Thats are my code :

```
<?php
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
@$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('https://www.blockchain.info/de/address/17pszxvAKTZo9RAFhSRkHKC9HXN1w9EXRs'));
var_dump($doc->getElementById('total_received'));
?>
```

I want to output the value from "Total Received" :S
I tried 2 hours but i failed

And sry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1):

You just need to echo out the `textContent` property on the element.

```
  echo "Total Received: " . $doc->getElementById('total_received')->textContent;
```